# WCF. REST architecture. How to get object from client in JSON (POST)

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, json, rest

I have method which have to add customer:

```
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    string CreateCustomer(Customer customer);
```

And i have a problem because all calls to this method fails!
The same method with **GET** working well (just return Customer object bu request id in url).
Response from wcf service:

```
Status: 400

 headers = {
        "Cache-Control" = private;
        "Content-Length" = 2900;
        "Content-Type" = "text/html";
        Date = "Tue, 22 Mar 2011 12:51:09 GMT";
        Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.0";
        "X-Aspnet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
        "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
    }


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
```

and i cannot debug method because problem occups before step in method.

I think that problem with my first argument **Customer customer**
How to do **POST** right? And how to work with it (Parse json on server)?

**In fiddler**

[image]

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

but i am not sure that this is the same problem like customer have!

Comment: There is a tool called Fiddler that can see what is being sent between the client and the server, I used this when developing a PoC for a WCF REST service - it was very useful: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: I use it. And cannot get any idea whats wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what problems you are getting, but when I looked into this, I had a different header:

`Content-Type = application/xml`

Also, you appear to have chopped off the body from your question, that could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Was invalid content type from customer request. Have to be **application/json**